# Jquery function of a widgets display:block not working well in IE/7/8

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I got this function, works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not well in IE. the .MAIN display:block doesn't work. ANY idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/cYrqY/35/
this example doesn't work well sorry

```
obj.click(function(){

                if(obj.ck_hotspot){
                    obj.ck_hotspot = false;
                }
                else {
                    if($.browser.msie){
                        obj.hotspot_bub.css("display","none");
                    }
                    else {
                        obj.hotspot_bub.fadeOut("slow");
                        $('.main').css('display','block');
                    }
                }
            })
            obj.hotspot.children("a").click(function(){
                obj.ck_hotspot = true;
                _this_bub = $(this).next(".hotspot_bub");

                if(_this_bub.css("display") == "none"){

                    if($.browser.msie){
                        obj.hotspot_bub.css("display","none");
                        _this_bub.css("display","block");

                    }
                    else {
                        obj.hotspot_bub.fadeOut("slow");
                        _this_bub.fadeIn("slow");
                        $('.main').css('display','none');
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do exactly ? We can read code but what is it supposed to do ?

Comment: the .MAIN is the default one. I want to hide the MAIN and display the other.

Comment: Your fiddle is useless. What is "obj" ? Complete it to at least provide something without errors !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cYrqY/41/

Comment: I've update the fiddle but still not luck

Answer (score 0):

Just as a first thought, you could save time by writing `$('main').hide();` It will automatically add the `display: none;` to your css and you can relax knowing you typed less :).

Same thing goes for `.show();`... it will add `display:block;`

I can't seem to get the jsFiddle to work at all in safari.

Comment: the MAIN is the default one. I want to hide the MAIN and display the other.